# java.sql.SQLException: Unknown system variable 'query_cache_size'

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jdbc

I have a app running with JDBC and get data from MySQL, but I can't build it because of this error :

```
java.sql.SQLException: Unknown system variable 'query_cache_size'
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:964) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2497) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2455) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1369) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.loadServerVariables(ConnectionImpl.java:3777) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:3240) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2249) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2035) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:790) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
```

I have file application.properties here

```
#specs.dir=/specs/
#
#################### Spring Boot Data Source Configuration ############
#spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/savingbooking?useSSL=false
#spring.datasource.username=root
#spring.datasource.password=ZAQ!2wsx
#spring.datasource.initialize=true
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
#spring.jpa.show-sql=true
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

Mysql workbench is 8.0 version

Comment: Where is the code causing the error ?

Comment: MySQL Workbench is a query tool for MySQL, it is not involved when you access a MySQL database from Java, so it is not relevant to your question.

Comment: It seems that it is a known bug https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=87846 Try upgrading your connector jar mysql-connector-java to 5.1.43 or higher

Answer (score 62, accepted):

`query_cache_size` was removed in MySQL 8. Check the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache.html).

It works with JDBC driver 5.1.44.

Comment: I am using mysql-connector-java version 6.0.3 using adding maven dependency in my project. and still I get the same error

Comment: @steven35 I am getting
`$ sudo mysql_upgrade -u root`
`Looking for 'mysql' as: mysql`
`Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: mysqlcheck`
`Error: Failed while fetching Server version! Could be due to unauthorized access.`
`FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed`
Please help

Comment: @DhavalBhoot you can use any later SQL connector. I used <version>8.0.12</version> and it worked seamlessly.

Comment: Latest version as for 2018 October is 8.0.13

Comment: Still getting same error "Unknown system variable 'query_cache_size'" with latest version mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.25 in java spring boot application.

Comment: This worked in combination with the answer from Enrique Jiménez Flores below

Answer (score 35):

> java.sql.SQLException: Unknown system variable 'query_cache_size'

In pom file of your project, just update the version of the dependency.

For example it's 6.0.2 of mysql java connector just update it to latest one like 8.0.11

It works!!!!

Comment: Updating driver version to 5.1.44 fixed the issue for me.  I am keeping driver version 5 because I still need to be able to connect to mySQL v5 on some servers, but now can connect to both.

Answer (score 13):

I had a similar problem.
I resolved it by **specifying the version** in mysql dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.45</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Worked like a charm for me.

Comment: I fix it base on @steven35 and it worked, but anw, thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 11):

For mysql 8:

mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar  (or above)
+ 
db.driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver  instead of com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Answer (score 10):

Try using MySQL 8.0.3
As can be seen on the docs, the query_cache_size was removed on MySQL8. JetBrains guys have suffered the same issue, is seems to be that it is fixed by updating the driver to the version MySQL JDBC driver v 5.1.44.

Comment: Updating the driver version to 5.1.44 fixed the issue for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I stuck on this issue, spend full one day and finally i got solution.

Solution :

> 1) Use exact mysql-connector-java jar or dependency as your mysql version.
>   2) if your mysql version is 8 or 6+ try to use this "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" driver class.

Answer (score 6):

**This exception is related to pom.xml dependency.**
**When I use below dependency in pox.xml:**

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.5</version>
 </dependency>
```

**It shows exception:Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unknown system variable query_cache_size**

**But, when I use below dependency:**

```
  <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.13</version>
  </dependency>
```

**It works.You have to use latest dependency**

Answer (score 5):

If you using MySql v8.0 then you should try fix this bug with

> mysql-connector-java-5.1.9

Answer (score 2):

Ok so what I did as metioned above. I just added the mysql-connector-java-5.1.4 to build path and ran the project on my server and connected fine to mysql

Answer (score 1):

just change the version of mysql
use this in pom.xml

```
<version>8.0.11</version>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  Below mention dependency it will work for you!

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.16</version>
    </dependency>
```