# Pantaho MySQL 8 connection error Driver class 'org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver' could not be found

Tags: mysql, pentaho, pentaho-data-integration, mysql-8.0

While upgrading ETL scripts for `Mysql 5.8` to `MySQL8` upgrade, as soon as I have updated the `data-integration/lib` jar to `mysql-connector-java-8.0.xx.jar`, it has started blowing with following `error`.

> Driver class 'org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver' could not be found, make sure the 'MySQL' driver (jar file) is installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did spent lot of time debugging and finally concluded, two things, I hope this may save others time in similar situation.

**Reason**: There is `hardcoded` jdbc driver name in `org.pentaho.di.core.database.MySQLDatabaseMeta`, and it always returns `org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver` which is removed and new `Driver` with name `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` or `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` should be used.

**Solutions** Any of below should be done to resolve.

1. Continue using the old `jdbc` jar.
2. Modify the `org.pentaho.di.core.database.MySQLDatabaseMeta` below method, compile and place it in `classes` directory.

   ```
   public String getDriverClass()  {
   if (getAccessType()==DatabaseMeta.TYPE_ACCESS_ODBC)
   {
       return "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
   }
   else
   {
       return "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
   }   }
   ```
3. Use the Generic database connection, then you can specify the driver class yourself. (Based on @Cyrus comment.)

Pentaho [open](https://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PDI-17341) bug reference.

Comment: You can also use the Generic database connection, then you can specify the driver class yourself.

Answer (score 6):

Could you please try to add both jars in

> data-integration/lib

As I did, I have added the lastest jar of `5.x` i.e `mysql-connector-java-5.1.48.jar`and the same version mine is 8.0.19 so i have added `mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar` i copied into location `data-integration/lib` .

After the test its working fine now.

Comment: this is actually working for me, but makes no sense.

Comment: me too just downloaded version 8 not 5; restarted spoon and new db connection test was successful

Answer (score 2):

i just to use Pentaho version 9.1 - 9.1.0.0-324 and mysql-connector-java-8.0.25

1- Make sure the Pentaho is not running.

2- Download the mysql connector at the link below.(https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java)

3- Copy the .jar file (mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar) and paste it in your Lib folder:

Example:  C:....\pentaho-data-integration\lib

4- Execute Pentaho (Spoon.bat)

Answer (score 1):

I was working with pdi 9.1, all I did to get rid of this error was to copy these two jar files in the `data-integration\lib`:

**mysql-connector-java-5.1.49.jar 

mysql-connector-java-5.1.49-bin.jar**

The link to the zip folder is mentioned in the above comments

Restart your spoon!
And that's it.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL driver for version 8 changed the class name. Therefore, you must set it as a Generic connection instead, and use com.mysql.jdbc.Driver as the class.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue by replacing `mysql-connector-java-5.1.42-bin.jar` with `mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar`

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49984267/java-sql-sqlexception-unknown-system-variable-query-cache-size)

Answer (score 0):

I am using `Pentaho 9.1.0.0-324` and had the same problem. I downloaded the `Everything` app and through it I found that I have already a file named `mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar` at `C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\Connector J 8.0\` folder. I simply copied the file into `C:\Pentaho\lib` and the problem solved. However, now I am getting another error as below:

> Connection failed. Verify all connection parameters and confirm that
> the appropriate driver is installed. Access denied for user
> 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

**Update**
I solved the `Access denied` error by reinstalling MySQL with legacy password option along with a password without non-alphabetical symbols.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to my as I tried to use Pentaho 9.4.0.0-342 with Xampp 8.2.4

I successfully solved it by downloading the jar_files.zip from [here](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.19/source-code), and copying the mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar to the data-integration\lib folder.