# Spring Boot - Unable to connect Azure MySQL database

Tags: spring-boot, application.properties, azure-mysql-database

I am new in connecting azure MySQL database from Spring boot application.

Below is the snippet mentioned in `application.properties`

```
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://XXXX.mysql.database.azure.com:3306/MyDbName
spring.datasource.username= ******
spring.datasource.password= ******
```

I have faced the following exception

```
org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Unknown system variable 'query_cache_size'
```

I have googled and somewhere it was mentioned that it is required to update the version of **MySQLConnector** to `8.0.13`

Please help me find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your exception , its not because of Azure mysql. Its because of system variable 'query_cache_size'. refer : [java.sql.SQLException: Unknown system variable 'query_cache_size'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49984267/java-sql-sqlexception-unknown-system-variable-query-cache-size)

Answer (score 0):

I too have met this bundle of joy on azure MySQL. As dvo mentions it places this variable in when it thinks it is under version 8.0.3.

From com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.java...

```
if (!versionMeetsMinimum(8, 0, 3)) {
    queryBuf.append(", @@query_cache_size AS query_cache_size");
    queryBuf.append(", @@query_cache_type AS query_cache_type");
}
```

But as my Azure MySQL version is 8.0.15 which matches my driver version then I suspect whilst the database *may well* be version 8 part of the stack the driver deals with is not.

**Edit:**

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/concepts-limits

> Current known issues
>
> MySQL server instance displays the wrong server version after connection is established. To get the correct server instance engine version, use the select  version(); command.

So I'm guessing that this is the problem and as it stands Azure MySQL 8 will not work with the java mysql connector.

I'll probably look at building the connector myself and hard coding in the version number to 8.0.15. What joy.

**Edit Edit:**

Modified ServerVersion.java parseVersion(…) to return

```
return new ServerVersion(8, 0, 15);
```

Which works around the problem enough for me to carry on with my work.

It's a problem Microsoft should be fixing ASAP on their side.