# Spring application fails through ProxySQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I am having some troubles to connect my multimodule maven project to proxysql.
When i connect to two different environments - one with **mysql 8** and other with **mysql 5**, the app is connecting fine and working fine.
When I connect to the proxy with mysql-connector via **cj** driver is throwing:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Unknown system variable 'query_cache_size'
```

Tried to change to **mariadb** and it throws:

```
 java.sql.SQLException: Unknown system variable 'tx_isolation'
```

***This happens with the latest versions of mysql-connector and mariadb client.***

When i created a simple maven module(non-spring) via ConnectionFactory is connecting! (mariadb client 2.7.0 or lower)
When i created a simple Spring app and tried to connect - same errors.
Does anyone could help here :(
I am using mybatis as ORM.
Maybe it's the jdbc version inside of the spring or the mybatis one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.sql.SQLException: Unknown system variable 'query\_cache\_size'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49984267/java-sql-sqlexception-unknown-system-variable-query-cache-size)

Comment: actually no, you need to "lie" the proxy and set it in the mysqlcnf.yaml that "mysql_server_version=8.0.27" or above 5

Answer (score 0):

It's too late, but I want to help someone face with this issue later.
Apply below setting into your ProxySQL.

```
update global_variables set variable_value="8.0.4 (ProxySQL)" where variable_name='mysql-server_version'; 
load mysql variables to run;save mysql variables to disk;
```

Thanks MarcoTusa for the explanation.
http://www.tusacentral.net/joomla/index.php/mysql-blogs/198-proxysql-server-version-impersonation.html